# Xcode 9 Playground does not work in Mojave

Tags: swift-playground, macos-mojave, xcode9.2

I have a new mac mini 2018 running Mojave. I copied my applications folder using migration assistant from my 2009 mac pro running Sierra, so Xcode version is 9.2.

Xcode starts and creating and building a single view app template works for both macOS and iOS.

But creating a playground results in endless spinning the wheel. I just add a line that prints the template "Hello, Playground" string to the console, but nothing happens on playground execution, the string does not even appear in the REPL Preview.

I downloaded Xcode 9.4.2 from the developer page - same result. I deleted, downloaded and re-installed 9.2, the same result.

I also downloaded Xcode 10.2.1 - here the playground seems to work.

Please note, that the problem already occurred when 9.2 was the only installation.

Following the advice from this thread:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/78869

I deleted these files in my user library, to no effect.

So what else can I do aside from re-installing the OS and installing every app from scratch?

UPDATE: I re-installed Mojave from scratch and installed nothing but 3 different Xcode 9 builds (9.2, 9.3 and 9.4) - in none of them does a playground work at all.

Comment: Why do you want to use a deprecated version of Xcode? [Xcode 10.1 is the oldest allowed version for iOS publication](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/devf16aefe3b) for instance.

Comment: Mostly because I have a very large playground with 50+ swift source files which runs fine under XCode 9.2 on Sierra on both my 2012 non retina MBP and my firmware-flashed 2009 MP. Now I have a new computer and I want to transfer the project slowly. On XCode 9 playgrounds do not work at all, not even the simplest template. On XCode 10.2 a simple playground works, but my large project does not compile. I am rather new to developing, so using a playground to test new classes and methods and then put them into individual source files has proven to be a very succesful learning approach for me.

Comment: Try: Xcode → Preferences... → Locations → Command Line Tools: select Xcode 9.4.2

Comment: That does not make any difference. Tried it with XCode 9.2 and 9.4.1 and the respective command line tools. Playgrounds remain unfunctional.